# Capture text blocks with a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have structured documents in the following format:

```
123456789|XXX|1234567|05/05/2012 00:00|81900153|Signed|LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME, M.S.|024813|XXX|3410080|DNR Order Verification:Scanned|

xyz pqs 123

[report_end]

123456789|XXX|1234567|05/05/2012 00:00|81900153|Signed|LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME, M.S.|024813|XXX|3410080|A Note|

xyz pqs 123

[report_end]
```

Where each record:

- starts with an 11-field line delimited by |
- has an intervening block of free text
- ends with the tag "[report_end]"

How can I capture these three elements with a regular expression?

My approach would be to

1. search each line that has 11 | characters;
2. search each line that has [report_end];
3. search whatever is in between these two lines.

But I don't know how to accomplish this with regular expressions.

Comment: Why regular expressions? Just read the 11-field line, then read lines until the end-report line comes, then read the next block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try with:

```
^(?P<fields>(?:[^|]+\|){11})(?P<text>[\s\S]+?)(?P<end>\[report_end\])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yI1xQ2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
r"((?:.*?\|){11}\s+(?:.*)\s+\[report_end\])"
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Match 1.    [0-157] `123456789|XXX|1234567|05/05/2012 00:00|81900153|Signed|LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME, M.S.|024813|XXX|3410080|DNR Order Verification:Scanned|

xyz pqs 123

[report_end]


Match 2.    [159-292]   `123456789|XXX|1234567|05/05/2012 00:00|81900153|Signed|LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME, M.S.|024813|XXX|3410080|A Note|

xyz pqs 123

[report_end]
```

---

**DEMO**

### https://regex101.com/r/xY5nI9/1

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
((?:.*?\|){11}\s+(?:.*)\s+\[report_end\])

Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((?:.*?\|){11}\s+(?:.*)\s+\[report_end\])»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:.*?\|){11}»
      Exactly 11 times «{11}»
      Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
      Match the character “|” literally «\|»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the regular expression below «(?:.*)»
      Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “[” literally «\[»
   Match the character string “report_end” literally «report_end»
   Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```

---

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENTS**

To get 3 groups you can use:

```
r"((?:.*?\|){11})\s+(.*)\s+(\[report_end\])
```

To loop all groups:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"((?:.*?\|){11})\s+(.*)\s+(\[report_end\])")

for (match1, match2, match3) in re.findall(pattern, string):
    print match1 +"\n"+ match2 +"\n"+ match3 +"\n"
```

---

**LIVE DEMO**

http://ideone.com/k8sA3k

Comment: Pedro, this almost what I'm looking for. I edited your expression to capture the three groups: ((?:.*?\|){11})(\s+(?:.*)\s+)(\[report_end\])  But how can iterate this over and over until the end of the file?

Comment: It's actually easy to create the groups, just surround them with `()`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: "But how can iterate this over and over..."  `all_answers = re.findall(r"((?:.*?\|){11}\s+(?:.*)\s+\[report_end\])", input_str)`

Comment: Check the live demo link